# How to detect handheld device iOS browsers with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, browser

I want that when I surf with my iPhone to my site that my iPhone get another text than when I surf with my Mac

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))
       || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))
       || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    document.write("you are surfing with an iPhone");
} else {
    document.write("you are not surfing with an iPhone")
}
</script>
```

It won't work.
Is there anyone who can help me?

Ps. sorry for my bad English, I'm from Belgium, Flanders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))
{
     alert("It's an iPhone or iPod");
}
```

Works a treat, I just tested it on my iPhone using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKYs9/).
​

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer :)

Comment: ahhhh :] elegant, lovely.